# How to git clone as a developer member of a gitlab project?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

We have a gitlab in our college server accessible from the web, so I created a repo there , i'm able to git clone , push , pull etc , but now I want to add my colleague as a developer contributor , so I set the visibility project as internal instead of private and added a member (they are listed if they signed up once in the gitlab)

Now the problem is when he tries to git clone as you see below it asks the owner password:

git clone git@gricad-gitlab.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr:zianinou/projet_java.git

We tried many variations of this command like changing the username but it didn't work, and I don't have clue to allow him to clone ....

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin page ( https://github.com/user/repo/admin ) and in the Collaborators tab you can add as many as you want ( since the free ones are public repos)

Edit: I just realized it's gitlab.

On project panel's right hand side, there's an option. Just make sure, your browser is open in full screen otherwise due to the media query breakpoint the browser doesn't display it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying I already know how to that , the issue is how the member can clone my project without giving him the owner password

Comment: @MadaraChannel Tried to help, thanks for acknowledging. I hope jsageyd answer will help. Will keep an eye for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone using an SSH URL (like the one you mention `git@...`), SSH takes care of all authentication.

To have SSH access work properly in GitLab:

1. Make sure that the user has a proper SSH keypair. GitHub [sic] provides a handy guide on how to do this, see [GitHub Help; SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/). The process is the same regardless of how you host your repository as long as you access it via SSH. It is a good idea to add a password protect your private key.
2. Make sure that the user's public SSH key has been added to his account. There should be an option in the user configuration to add this.
3. Done.

Given that you have the above set up, the password prompt you are getting is likely asking for the password of the SSH private key, that you set when you created it.

To avoid this prompt from showing up every time you connect to the server, you can use `ssh-agent`. Details on this are explained in the link in step 1 above.